# Why my radar chart (HighCharts) is not fully filled to its parent container's size?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

HTML:

```
  <div id="screenshot-area">
    <div id="container"></div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
  #screenshot-area {
    max-width: 1160px;
    height: 588px;
  }
  #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

JS:

```
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{point.y}'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'line',
      polar: true,
      spacingTop: 0
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ["目力","攻撃力","防御力","覇気"],
      tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
      lineWidth: 0
    },
    yAxis: {
      gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
      lineWidth: 0,
      min: 0
    },
    series: [{
      data: [9,6,5,1]
    }]
  })
```

You can view the result here: http://output.jsbin.com/guzisekezu

the chart is not taking the full size of it's parent, which is `#screenshot-area`, there are a lot of space between them.

Comment: Which Browser are you using? For me on Chrome, the white chart-area is taking the whole parent-height, see red-bordered on http://jsbin.com/gagulirono/edit?html,output

Comment: @niorad I'm also using chrome, are you seeing spaces between the chart and the container?

Comment: this is how it looks for me: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qkl874qyhhfq4iq/Screenshot%202017-10-01%2013.52.07.png?dl=0

Comment: @niorad yeah me too. Do you think the chart size in this case is correct?

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate size of the polar chart, use the `size` property from the `pane` object.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/pane.size

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vLfvnw6n/